# Não está setando o valor na query.setParameter ao tentar fazer uma consulta no banco

Tags: java, mysql, jsf

Estou com um problema na hora de setar um valor na `query.setParameter`. Uso *EcliseLink* e MySQL, fiz uma consulta sem setar parâmetros e funcionou, o que será que pode ser?

Classe onde tento fazer a consulta:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package br.com.redew.dao;

import br.com.redew.entidade.Funcionario;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
import javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException;
import javax.persistence.Query;

/**
 *
 * @author Desenvolvimento
 */
public class FuncionarioDao extends GenericoDao<Funcionario, Integer> implements Serializable {

    public Funcionario autenticar(Funcionario funcionario) throws NoResultException, NonUniqueResultException {
        Query query = getEm().createNamedQuery("Funcionario.autenticar");
        query.setParameter("email", funcionario.getEmail());
        query.setParameter("senha", funcionario.getSenha());
        return (Funcionario) query.getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

Classe GenericoDao:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package br.com.redew.dao;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;

/**
 *
 * @author weder
 */
public class GenericoDao<T, ID> implements Serializable {

    private EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private EntityManager em;
    private Class<T> classe;

    public GenericoDao() {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("br.com.redew_redew_war_1.0.0PU");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
        classe = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    public T find(ID id) {
        return getEm().find(classe, id);
    }

    public Object insert(T Objeto) {
        getEm().getTransaction().begin();
        getEm().persist(Objeto);
        getEm().flush();
        getEm().getTransaction().commit();
        return Objeto;
    }

    public Object update(T Objeto) {
        getEm().getTransaction().begin();
        getEm().merge(Objeto);
        getEm().flush();
        getEm().getTransaction().commit();
        return Objeto;
    }

    public Object delete(T Objeto) {
        getEm().getTransaction().begin();
        getEm().remove(Objeto);
        getEm().flush();
        getEm().getTransaction().commit();
        return Objeto;
    }

    public List callNamedQuery(String namedQuery) {
        Query q = getEm().createNamedQuery(namedQuery);
        return q.getResultList();
    }

    public List callNativeNamedQuery(String query) {
        Query q = getEm().createNativeQuery(query);
        return q.getResultList();
    }

    public EntityManager getEm() {
        return em;
    }
}
```

Dá esse erro:

> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] 
>    (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): 
>    org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>    Internal Exception: 
>    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No 
>    operations allowed after connection closed.
>    Error Code: 0
>    Call: SELECT id, email, nome, senha, telefone, id_empresa FROM funcionario 
>    WHERE ((email = ?) AND (senha = ?))
>       bind => [2 parameters bound]
>    Query: ReadAllQuery(name="Funcionario.autenticar" referenceClass=Funcionario 
>    sql="SELECT id, email, nome, senha, telefone, id_empresa FROM funcionario WHERE 
>    ((email = ?) AND (senha = ?))")

Comment: Você está tentando fazer consulta com a conexao fechada. Verifique a conexao antes da consulta.

Comment: Antes de consultar eu verifico a conexão em um "GenericoDao".

Comment: Se possivel, adicione um trecho onde você chama esse método para ver a origem do problema. O erro é claro, está tentando fazer uma query mas a conexao está fechada.

Comment: Já editei a pergunta está la as classes :)

Comment: Você poderia incluir a classe `Funcionario` para que se possa avaliar a sua native query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já resolvi ficou assim obrigado pessoal:

```
public List<Funcionario> autenticar(Funcionario funcionario) {
        Query query = getEm().createNamedQuery("Funcionario.autenticar");
        query.setParameter("email", funcionario.getEmail());
        query.setParameter("senha", funcionario.getSenha());
        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

Comment: O que fez de diferente? Esse código está praticamente idêntico ao que estava dando problema da pergunta.

Comment: Estou retornando uma lista agora 'query.getResultList();' ao invés de 'query.getSingleResult();'